# SQL - Multiple joins with WHERE & Order By

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sql-order-by, where-clause

Database:

```
    Car:                          Contract:          Customer:
    Carplate (PRKEY)              Contractid(PRKEY)  CustomerID(PRIK)
    PRICE                         Miles              Customername
    Leased(0Free- 1Leased)        Carplate(FKEY)     Zipcode
                                                     ContractID FKEY)
                                                     Carplate(FKEY)
```

I want to get all leased Cars (=1) with their current **miles**, **Customername** and **group by(mistake-order by)** the customer's **zipcode**.

Syntax

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON 
     table1.primaryKey=table2.FKEY INNER JOIN 
     table3 ON table2.primaryKey=table3.FKEY
```

Problem: I do not understand the propper use of INNER JOIN here and the where clause.

```
Select Car.Leased, Contract.Miles, Customer.Customername, Customer.Zipcode
From Car 
INNER JOIN Contract  on Car.Carplate = Contract.Carplate
INNER JOIN Customer  on Contract.Carplate = Customer.Carplate
where Car.Leased = 1
order by Customer.Zipcode ASC
```

Tried to create the code via the Syntax. It's right?

Comment: Looks just fine. Do you get the expected result?

Comment: `JOINs` end up in creating several combinations of the rows of the table involved depending on the type of it - `INNER, OUTER, LEFT, RIGHT,` etc. The `where` clause filters out the relevant.

Comment: Iam learning by paper.

Comment: Obvious question about the database itself: if `customer` table is a child of `contract`, based on `contractid`, and `contract` is a child of `car` based on `carplate`, why do you **also** have `carplate` in `customer`? Does that reference to cars mean a customer linked to a car **other than** the car in the contract? If so, you need to explain which link from customer to car should be used. (More likely, that is not the case - the only car for a customer is the car in the contract, and you don't need `carplate` in `customer` table.)

Answer (score 1):

> I do not understand the propper use of INNER JOIN here and the where
>   clause

`INNER JOIN` will return common data **between** two tables and `WHERE` clause will refine data from **one specific table**.

> I want to get all leased Cars (=1) with their current miles,
>   Customername and **group by the customer's zipcode**.

As per your query, your are doing `order by Customer.Zipcode ASC`. So, there is difference in `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`

Comment: More specific question:
First From is only for Car, why not for Customer and and Contract?
2nd:
Syntax is always like this? = t1.primarykey=t2.fkey
t2.fkey=t3.fkey ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you would also want to join the Customer table using ContractID - the way I am reading the table structure, Carplate could show up for multiple Customers, if the car is ever re-sold. You also don't necessarily need to Select Leased, since you know you are only getting records where Leased = 1. But if you want to keep it as a sanity check, no harm done.

```
SELECT Contract.Miles, Customer.Customername, Customer.Zipcode
FROM Car
INNER JOIN Contract ON Car.Carplate = Contract.Carplate
INNER JOIN Customer ON Contract.Contractid = Customer.ContractID AND 
Car.Carplate = Customer.Carplate
WHERE Car.Leased = 1
ORDER BY Customer.Zipcode ASC
```

Comment: Ah okay,
so i need to compare every table with each other in the "last" inner join to get the Customer Results:
Syntax like:
From t1
INNER JOIN t2 on t1.PRIK = t2.FKEY
INNER JOIN t3 on t2.FKEY= t3 FKEY && t2.FKEY = t3.FKEY
correct?

Comment: Not necessarily. It all depends on the specific tables you are joining. You can have t2 with a foreign key to t1, and t3 with a foreign key to t2 but no relation to t1, and you can still join all 3.

Comment: Ah okay, in this case the last comparison is needed, to get the actual "owner" of the car and not all old "car owner's" off the database.